# Cannot Detect When User Scrolls to the Bottom of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to detect when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        // when scroll to bottom of the page
    }
});
```

However, instead of telling me when I scroll to the bottom of the page, the if statement becomes true when I scroll all the way to the top. Why is this happening? Thanks so much.  The reason I need to detect when the user scrolls to the bottom is so that I can dynamically load content from a server. I don't think this matter, but I am using Flask on the backend and the malfunctioning page is rendered as a template with jinja-2.

Comment: Adding this to a jsfiddle results in this: https://jsfiddle.net/apwkz9mb/1/ It works fine for me.

Comment: Can not replicate the same!

Comment: Is it possible that there is some sort of conflict with the templating engine? If there is one, how could I get around it?

Comment: Wow! Finally, I figured out that the reason it wasn't working was that I forgot the doctype declaration!

Answer (score 0):

```
_onScrollHandler(event){
if(event.target.scrollHeight - event.target.scrollTop === event.target.clientHeight){
console.log('Reacehd Bottom')
} 
}
```

Call this function when onscroll event occurs and from event arg you can get the scrollHeight scrollTop and clientheight.
Please try with this one